# Shortening Code by Using Loops/Functions to get rid of Repeated Words

Tags: python

In my Intro to CS class, we have an assignment where we have to shorten the lyrics of "The Fox" using Python. There are 7 lines with repeated words and 2 sets of consecutive repeated lines. I used functions to repeat the consecutive lines, but I can't think of a way to use loops or functions to shorten the lines with repeated words. A few examples of those lines with repeated words:

print("Dog goes woof, cat goes meow.")

print("Bird goes tweet, and mouse goes squeak.")

print("Cow goes moo. Frog goes croak, and the elephant goes toot.")

These lines repeat "goes," but I am just not sure how to shorten the code using loops or functions so that it prints in the same way above but with less code.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: One approach would be something like this: you have comma in the middle, so you can split each string into 2 f-strings, and every f-string will have the word **goes** once thus if you have a tuple or a list with 2 items at least, you can iterate and plug the word **goes**  - turn "Dog goes woof, cat goes meow." into (f"Dog {} woof", f"cat {} meow") and then for each item plug the word **goes** in that is repeated - either using lambda or a loop.